# gnustl (libstdc++) to llvm (libc++ ) errors

Tags: android, c++, libstdc++, libc++

I am started to get these errors after I have migrated from gnustl to libc++. I could not find anything over internet on this. and do not have any more information.
I am continuing my investigation on this and as my investigation proceeds I will update this thread with my findings.

```
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.9\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\__tree(1819,22) :  error: the specified comparator type does not provide a const call operator [-Werror,-Wuser-defined-warnings]
                     __trigger_diagnostics()), "");
                     ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.9\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\set(400,28) :  note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__ndk1::__tree<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> >::~__tree' requested here
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS set
                           ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.9\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\memory(1550,14) :  note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__ndk1::allocator_traits<HeapAllocator<std::__ndk1::__tree_node<std::__ndk1::__value_type<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > >, void *> > >::__destroy<std::__ndk1::pair<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *const, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > > >' requested here
            {__destroy(__has_destroy<allocator_type, _Tp*>(), __a, __p);}
             ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.9\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\__tree(1833,24) :  note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__ndk1::allocator_traits<HeapAllocator<std::__ndk1::__tree_node<std::__ndk1::__value_type<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > >, void *> > >::destroy<std::__ndk1::pair<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *const, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > > >' requested here
        __node_traits::destroy(__na, _NodeTypes::__get_ptr(__nd->__value_));
                       ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.9\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\__tree(1821,3) :  note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__ndk1::__tree<std::__ndk1::__value_type<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > >, std::__ndk1::__map_value_compare<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, std::__ndk1::__value_type<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > >, std::__ndk1::less<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *>, true>, HeapAllocator<std::__ndk1::__value_type<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > > > >::destroy' requested here
  destroy(__root());
  ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.9\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\map(805,28) :  note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__ndk1::__tree<std::__ndk1::__value_type<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > >, std::__ndk1::__map_value_compare<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, std::__ndk1::__value_type<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > >, std::__ndk1::less<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *>, true>, HeapAllocator<std::__ndk1::__value_type<RichValueTypeReservedKeyInfoManager *, Set<IRichValue::Type, IRichValueUtil::TypeComparer, HeapAllocator<IRichValue::Type> > > > >::~__tree' requested here
class _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS map
                           ^
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.9\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\__tree(970,7) :  note: from 'diagnose_if' attribute on '__trigger_diagnostics':
      _LIBCPP_DIAGNOSE_WARNING(!__invokable<_Compare const&, _Tp const&, _Tp const&>::value,
      ^                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
f:/nugetcache\androidndk.16.1.9\sources\cxx-stl\llvm-libc++\include\__config(1101,20) :  note: expanded from macro '_LIBCPP_DIAGNOSE_WARNING'
    __attribute__((diagnose_if(__VA_ARGS__, "warning")))
                   ^           ~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is telling you that you're passing a comparison object to a set or map that has a non-const `operator ()`.

You can either fix your comparison operator or turn off `-Werror` (which will make that a warning rather than an error)

I would take a look at `std::__ndk1::less` if I were you.

Comment: Yes, making function const is fixing the issue but how was it working with gnustl, is the question.

Comment: libstdc++ does not detect and warn the requirement that the comparison function be const - many set operations will work with a non-const `op()`. But some will not:

Comment: for example: `const set<int, myLess<int>> s; s.find(0);` will fail to compile with a very strange error message if myLess's `operator()` is not marked const. libc++ diagnoses this for you.

Comment: You'll get a very similar error with GCC 8 ([live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/q1CWHSPzFsIiHRiy)) but older versions didn't bother to enforce that requirement, so some set operations would work, and some wouldn't. Now it always gives an error if your comparison object is buggy, just like libc++ does.